# Euler's Totient Function: $\phi(n)\geq n\cdot 2^{-r}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-factorization, totient-function

My friend's teacher made a list with this problem: If $n$ has $r$ distinct prime factors, show that:

> $$\phi(n)\geq n\cdot 2^{-r}$$

I tried to help her, but I am not very good in number theory

Comment: yes, exactly. The hint that José gave me helped me solve it already. I just can't mark the question as answered yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $P$ is prime, then $1-\frac1p\geqslant\frac12$. Therefore, if $p_1,\ldots,p_r$ are prime numbers, then$$\left(1-\frac1{p_1}\right)\left(1-\frac1{p_2}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac1{p_r}\right)\geqslant 2^{-r}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't think about this 1−1/p⩾1/2 I came close to this and ended up proving Euler's product formula kkkkk

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$
\phi(n)=n\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)
$$
where $n=p_1p_2\dotsb p_r$. Use the fact that $p_i\ge 2$ to bound the product.

Comment: Note that this is has the exact same idea as the answer @JoséCarlosSantos provided above.